# How to make a question more focused when there are extremely few answers?

Tags: discussion

This question was closed for not being focused enough, but as the comments point out, it's a clear question but an issue never heard of before. How does it become more focused than that?

[Have movies with time travel ever shown how they get to a point in space in the past?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110549/have-movies-with-time-travel-ever-shown-how-they-get-to-a-point-in-space-in-the?noredirect=1#comment188596_110549)

Comment: To me it looks like that close reason was used by lack of a better one. IMHO this isn't a good question, because it is unanswerable. Time travel doesn't exist, and thus asking for an explanation of its mechanics is like asking for an explanation of magic or shapeshifting etc.

Comment: The lack of focus might also be applied to the fact that there are numerous movies and TV series that use time travel, and if they offer a technical explanation, it might be a different one. Thus you'd need to ask about a particular movie/TV series, but then the answer would 99.99% likely be "they don't explain it". And they don't explain it for the reason I state in my first comment: time travel does not exist and any of its logical holes are simply glossed over.